# How to change spriteKit SKSpriteNode texture

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a Swift 4.2 SpriteKit scene and I want to programatically change the texture of an SKSpriteNode.
How do I access the SKSpriteNode contained in the SKNode to change the texture?
Here is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var spritekitsceneFG: WKInterfaceSKScene!  

   var SpriteTick1 = SKNode()

   SpriteTick1 = (spritekitsceneFG.scene?.childNode(withName: "SKSpriteTick1"))!

   Want to change texture here!   

   print(SpriteTick1)
```

Printing out the SKNode gives the following output:

```
<SKSpriteNode> name:'SKSpriteTick1' texture:[<SKTexture> 'tick' (64 x 64)] position:{-48.000137, -56.000198} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{48, 48} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00
```

I want to be able to programatically change the texture here, the texture is called 'tick'

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found A way to do it like this. Any better ideas much welcomed.

```
   var SpriteTick1 = SKSpriteNode()
   SpriteTick1 = (spritekitsceneFG.scene?.childNode(withName: "SKSpriteTick1"))! as! SKSpriteNode
   let textureCross = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cross")
   SpriteTick1.texture = textureTick
```